# How to configure Elastic beanstalk classic load balancer to terminate HTTPS using the CLI

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

I use the Elastic Beanstalk CLI to deploy my Spring Boot application to EB.
It all works correctly as long as I don't configure HTTPS.

According to the [userdocs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html) all I should need to do is create a .config file in my .ebextensions folder with the following content

```
option_settings:
    aws:elb:listener:443:
        SSLCertificateId: <arn for cert>
        ListenerProtocol: HTTPS
        InstancePort: 5000
        InstanceProtocol: HTTP
    aws:elb:listener:80:
        ListenerEnabled: false
```

However, if I create my environment with that configuration the health checks fail due to being unable to communicate with the ELB.  Looking at the environment in the AWS console both the HTTP and HTTPS listener ports have been disabled and the SSL cert is not associated with the load balancer.

Given the change in behaviour I think it's safe to say that the .config file is being picked up and applied, even if the config is somehow incorrect.

If I manually try to enable the HTTPS listener through the EB web GUI at this stage I get the following error.

```
LoadBalancerHTTPSPort: You have specified both the @deprecated(:default.aws:elb:loadbalancer:LoadBalancerHTTPSPort) option as well as one in the new aws:elb:listener:443 namespace. The :default.aws:elb:loadbalancer:LoadBalancerHTTPSPort option will be ignored.
```

So I can't even enable it manually even if I wanted to.

There are a binch of questions/answers on here that talk about uploading custom nginx conf files.  I believe those to now be out of date and not applicable, but if someone can point me to something that works given the current state of EB I'm happy to go with that.

**Some information for reference below**

I'm using ACM to host my (self-signed) cert. For my purposes self-signed certs are ok while I test this. I don't know if that's confusing the load balancer, though the docs do mention using self-signed certs.  I'll be moving to a proper cert later.

My .elasticbeanstalk/config.yaml looks like this

```
branch-defaults:
  default:
    environment: <name>
deploy:
  artifact: target/<jar name>.jar
global:
  application_name: <App name>
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: <key name>
  default_platform: Java 8
  default_region: eu-west-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: null
  workspace_type: Application
```

The commandline I run to create the environment is

```
eb create <name> -c <name> --elb-type classic
```

EB CLI version info

```
eb --version
EB CLI 3.10.5 (Python 2.7.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

1.)

Have you uploaded your server certificate to ACM? It's unclear if you created with ACM or a 3rd party which would need uploading to ACM.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/import-certificate.html

2.)

Check the order of precedence for configs in Elastic Beanstalk.

.ebextensions have low precedence, so those option values could be overridden by higher precedence option settings.

The solution would be to update your cert in the console GUI. Navigate to the GUI https://aws.amazon.com/ 
Go to your elastic beanstalk gui -> click your environment -> click configuration on the left side bar -> click the gear icon next to "load balancing".

Now you'll see a list of ELB option settings. Choose your cert from the dropdown menu: "SSL certificate ID" and save.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html#configuration-options-precedence